# Why reverse the remainder during decimal to binary conversion?

Tags: math, binary

There is a particular method of converting a decimal (with a decimal point, like xx.xx) to a binary number. It is detailed here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-decimal-fraction-binary-number/

I can apply this process but am having trouble understanding WHY it works.

Basically, it calculates the left side of the decimal point separately from the right side - this part I have no issue with.
For example, if we have 6.9, it will start by calculating the left side: 6.

6 divided by 2 gives us 3, with a remainder of 0.

3 divided by 2 gives us 1, with a remainder of 1.

1 divided by 2 gives us 0, with a remainder of 1.

For some reason, it now takes the REVERSE of this, which is 110, and this magically becomes 6.
I don't understand why the remainder of the least significant division (1 divided by 2) is now used in the most significant bit of the answer, and this somehow works.

Similarly confused about why the method for the right hand side works.

Does anyone have some intuition they can share about this particular process of converting decimals to binaries? Again, I have no problem performing the calculation as the computation is quite easy. I simply don't understand why this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it like this :

A binary representation `b_n, b_(n-1), .., b_0` (least significant bit on the right) represents the number

`k = b_n*2^n + b_(n-1)*2^(n-1) + ... + b_0*2^0` (remember that 2^0 is just 1).

To get the least significant bit, you want to know whether this number divides evenly into 2's, because if it doesn't then you know that `b_0 == 1` because all the other terms surely divide evenly, as they all have some positive power of 2 in front. Thus the remainder from the division by two is `b_0`. Don't divide just yet, only get the remainder and write it down.

Now we would like to get rid of that last bit and start over again to get the next one. How can we do that? Simply divide k by two. Because then you get:

`k/2 = b_n*2^(n-1) + b_(n-1)*2^(n-2) + ... + b_1*2^0` (Divide each term in the sum by 2, thus decreasing the power. The last term disappears because it was either 0 or 1, which both give 0 when divided by 2)

Or written in binary (without the powers of two) : `b_n, b_(n-1), .., b_1`.

Now we get a new number which is simply the same as before where the least significant bit has been thrown away and everything shifted to the right. So we can start this whole process again with `k/2` to get `b_1`. And then `b_2`. And so on.

Here I separated getting the remainder and dividing to make it clearer, but you can do them at the same time if you want to, it's the same thing.

I hope you see how, during this process, we get the bits from right to left, which is why you want to flip the whole thing in the end if you have been writing them down from left to right.